# Rest API неправильный формат данных

Tags: wordpress

Попробовал получить записи(posts) через Rest API в wordpress endpoint /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/95
Все поля где кириллица такого формата:

```
"title":{"rendered":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043a\u0430"}
```

Если цифры или латиница то все нормально показывает.
Как можно установить правильный формат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не "не прафильный формат", а unicode escape sequence, в которые, в соответствии со стандартом JSON, должны преобразовываться символы не входящие в диапазон ASCII. Просто преобразуйте строку, содержащую JSON, в данные c помощью JSON.parse() (Зависит от того, какой язык вы используете)

```
console.log(JSON.parse('"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0435\u0440\u043a\u0430"'))
```